# How to get AWS kops based kubernetes cluster IP address to connect with gitlab CICD pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create basic gitlab CICD pipeline which will deploy my node.js based backend to AWS kops based k8s cluster.For that I have created `gitlab-ci.yml` file which will use for deploy whole CICD pipeline, however I am getting confused with how to get kubernetes cluster IP address so I can use it in gitlab-ci.yml to set  as `- kubectl config set-cluster k8s --server="$CLUSTER_ADDRESS"`
where I want `CLUSTER_ADDRESS` to configure with gitlab in gitlab-ci.yml.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  REGISTRY: $CI_REGISTRY
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  K8S_DEPLOYMENT_NAME: deployment/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
  CONTAINER_NAME: $CI_PROJECT_NAME

stages:
  - build
  - build-docker
  - deploy


build-docker:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build-docker
  services:
    - docker:dind
  tags:
    - privileged
  only:
    - Test
  script:
    script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $REGISTRY
    - docker build --network host -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG -t $IMAGE_NAME:latest .
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:latest
deploy-k8s-(stage):
  image:
    name: kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - privileged
  # Optional: Manual gate
  when: manual
  dependencies:
    - build-docker
  script:
    - kubectl config set-cluster k8s --server="$CLUSTER_ADDRESS"
    - kubectl config set clusters.k8s.certificate-authority-data $CA_AUTH_DATA
    - kubectl config set-credentials gitlab-service-account --token=$K8S_TOKEN
    - kubectl config set-context default --cluster=k8s --user=gitlab-service-account --namespace=default
    - kubectl config use-context default
    - kubectl set image $K8S_DEPLOYMENT_NAME $CI_PROJECT_NAME=$IMAGE_TAG
    - kubectl rollout restart $K8S_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
```

Comment: In general you will be much happier using their built-in kubernetes integration, but the specific answer to your question is to set `CLUSTER_ADDRESS` as a project or group level [CI/CD Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html)

Comment: Hi @mdaniel thanks for link and information however I have already set environment variables name CLUSTER_ADDRESS in that project however here I am confused how to get the CLUSTER_ADDRESS as I am running on AWS I tried to get cluster address using 'kops get -o yaml' so I got master address so I used it however I am not still confirm that would be fine or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current kubeconfig context is set to the cluster in question, you can run the following to get the cluster address you want:

```
kubectl config view --minify --raw \
    --output 'jsonpath={.clusters[0].cluster.server}'
```

You can add `--context <cluster name>` if not.

In most cases this will be `https://api.<cluster name>`.